# Filter BigCommerce products on a custom field using API

Tags: bigcommerce

I have products in my catalog that benefit from a rebate.
If a product does have a rebate, he has a custom field "rebate" set to 1.

I want to display a page with all products having a rebate, and I'm doing it trough the API.
As I'm new, I'm wondering what should be the syntax to get the custom field value and filter on it.

I'm testing with something like this :
https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v3/catalog/products?include=custom_fields&rebate=1

But not working at all ... I'm getting a 422, saying that rebate is not a valid filter.

Thank you for your help,
Jaad

Answer (score 1):

That's correct--`custom_field` keys are not a valid filter on a product request. To see the list of valid parameters you can use with a Get Product request, see our documentation here (expand the Query Params section):

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/catalog/catalog-api/products/getproducts

You could make the request for all product data and sort the products by custom field key within your application. Or, if you wanted to limit the request to only rebate products, you could tag all rebate products in a Rebate category (this category could even be hidden). Then you could filter the request to get all products that are in that category:

https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v3/catalog/products?categories:in={rebateCategoryID}

Comment: but how do you filter the request ?
The URL you provided will list all products in a given category, right ?
Does filtering needs to be done after all data is loaded, with some javascript, or is there another way ?

Comment: Yes, the URL I provided will list all products in a given category. This is an alternative solution to retrieving all rebate products in the API call, since custom fields are not a valid filter on the request. You would first have to create a category (Rebate) and put all rebate products into that category. You could hide that category on the front end. But this request would return only products in that rebate category. Otherwise you would have to write some middleware in your app to do the filtering by custom field key.